# How to remove the fake OS options from Ubutnu grub loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-10

I have a pc with SSD and HDD drive on it. I installed the windows 10 OS and then installed ubuntu as a dual boot on the SSD. I now found the ubuntu grub loader see two windows OS!. One not work and the other is what I just installed. I used the ubuntu boot-repair tool to create a summary of what is going. and I found this:

```
================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS CurrentSession on sdb4
OS#2:   Windows 10 (boot) on sdb1
OS#3:   Windows 8 or 10 on sdb2
```

here is a screenshot of my SSD (the sdb)

[image]

**Why this happens ?? and How to fix this issue?**

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? Microsoft has required UEFI with gpt partitioning since 2012, but your partitions may be the old MBR? Grub2's os-prober just looks for Windows boot files like bootmgr or bootmgfw.efi. Often good idea to have copies as backups, but then you get the multiple grub entries.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo os-prober`?

Comment: @oldfred all disks are MBR with BIOS (Legacy) booting

Comment: @Terrance `/dev/sdb1:Windows 10:Windows:chain`

Comment: @Omar_Hafez If you run `sudo update-grub` there will only be 1 Windows entry for the grub menu since the prober only detects one.